# D3.js custom edge rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am trying to make a graph which is sort of similar to a map. Here, I use a force-directed graph in which the nodes are locations and the edges are the paths between locations.
However, I can't seem to find any documentation on how to render an edge any different than a line with color attributes. (which I am doing now but looks kind of bland)

Is there some kind of way to have the edges custom rendered, for example, a repeated image of some sorts? Or even more specific, in my case for example, as a dirt path or similar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post an image of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: A good image of what I want isn't really available online, so I've done my best in paint: https://imgur.com/a/CIpStjD

So, instead of rendering the edge as a colored line, I want it to be customized to look like some sort of path (in the case of my paint example, a dirt path). If there isn't a functionality to render edges like this, is there maybe something to give edges a different pattern, route or anything else to make them look like anything else than a straight line with a color?

Comment: Another possibility for me would be to make the width of the edge converge or diverge. I.E. it start from node X on width 20 (based on some datum from X) and ends at node Y on width 10 (based on some datum from Y). This would also suffice. However, again, I cannot find any documentation on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<filter>`:

```html
<svg>
  <filter id="my-filter">
    <feFlood flood-color="orange" flood-opacity="0.75" in="SourceGraphic"></feFlood>
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"></feComposite>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
    <feComponentTransfer result="glow1">
      <feFuncA type="linear" slope="4" intercept="0"></feFuncA>
    </feComponentTransfer>
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode in="glow1"></feMergeNode><feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  <path d="M 10,10 L 100,100" filter="url(#my-filter)" stroke="orange" stroke-width="3"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know of filters for edges, so this comes quite close to what I want! However, I have two questions;

1. Using feImage, I have rendered the edges as the required image. However, since all edges have a different rotation based on source/target position, the images are not placed correctly ( see https://imgur.com/a/M8Dyblf , dont mention the white background ). How can I best solve this?

2. How can I now go about diverging/converging the link? Using feMorphology, I can dilate or erode the entire link, but I cant seem to find a filter which diverges or converges the edge.

Comment: I think you're asking two different questions here. I suggest to post a new question (or two) with more specific information about the problem you need to solve. If you find my answer useful, please mark as correct and/or upvote